# NavigationBar not show up inside ScrollView.Provider shoutem/animation

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I try to use shoutem in my project, when i try using @shoutem/animation to make my screen look better when do somthing like scroll list, but i have problem. Please look my code below here:

here is my import :

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Screen, Text, Image, Tile, Title, Subtitle, NavigationBar, View, ScrollView } from '@shoutem/ui'; 
import { ScrollDriver, } from '@shoutem/animation';
```

```js
 return (
            <ScrollView.DriverProvider>
                <Screen>
                    <NavigationBar
                        styleName='clear'
                        animationName="solidify"
                        title={restaurant.name}
                        share={{
                            title: restaurant.name,
                            link: restaurant.url,
                        }}
                    />
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Image
                            styleName="large-portrait placeholder"
                            source={{ uri: restaurant.image.url }}
                            animationName="hero"
                        >
                            <Tile animationName="hero">
                                <Title>{restaurant.name}</Title>
                                <Subtitle>{restaurant.address}</Subtitle>
                            </Tile>
                        </Image>
                        <View
                            styleName="solid"
                            style={{
                                backgroundColor: 'white',
                                height: 700,
                                padding: 15,
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text>
                                Gaspar is a delightful French restaurant in
            San Francisco\’s Financial District that is inspired by the romantic,
            bustling Paris of old. Located near famed Union Square, our richly-designed
            interiors make you feel as if you are truly in Paris and provide the perfect
            setting for enjoying our exquisite classic and modern French fare such as Duck
            Leg Confit and always popular Steak Frites. Gaspar offers two stories of dining
            in addition to full bars both upstairs and downstairs and an exclusive room
            reserved to hold the largest selection of Cognac in San Francisco.
            In addition to our all day menu, we offer live jazz music on Saturdays.
          </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Screen>

            </ScrollView.DriverProvider>
        );
```

And here is my error, when i scroll down, still got nothing showup.
[image]

Please suggest me some solution for resolve it, thanks so much guys

Comment: Hey @Chu Việt Hưng, could you post the imports of your screen? Because if you are importing `NavigationBar` from `@shoutem/ui`, you don't even need `ScrollView.DriverProvider`. Then I can post you a complete answer on how to make your `NavigationBar` animated.

Comment: here is my import :
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Screen,
    Text,
    Image,
    Tile,
    Title,
    Subtitle,
    NavigationBar,
    View,
    ScrollView
} from '@shoutem/ui';
import {
    ScrollDriver,
} from '@shoutem/animation';

Comment: i has added import of my screen! Please check and help me @IvanVukovic

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationBar` imported from `shoutem/ui` doesn't know to work with `ScrollView.DriverProvider`

So to achieve the wanted animation, I would do something like this:

```js
 MyScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.scrollDriver = new ScrollDriver();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Screen>
          <NavigationBar
              styleName='clear'
              animationName="solidify"
              title={restaurant.name}
              share={{
                  title: restaurant.name,
                  link: restaurant.url,
              }}
              driver={this.scrollDriver}
          />
          <ScrollView driver={this.scrollDriver}>
              <Image
                  styleName="large-portrait placeholder"
                  source={{ uri: restaurant.image.url }}
                  animationName="hero"
              >
                  <Tile animationName="hero">
                      <Title>{restaurant.name}</Title>
                      <Subtitle>{restaurant.address}</Subtitle>
                  </Tile>
              </Image>
              <View
                  styleName="solid"
                  style={{
                      backgroundColor: 'white',
                      height: 700,
                      padding: 15,
                  }}
              >
                  <Text>
                      Gaspar is a delightful French restaurant in
                    San Francisco\’s Financial District that is inspired by the romantic,
                    bustling Paris of old. Located near famed Union Square, our richly-designed
                    interiors make you feel as if you are truly in Paris and provide the perfect
                    setting for enjoying our exquisite classic and modern French fare such as Duck
                    Leg Confit and always popular Steak Frites. Gaspar offers two stories of dining
                    in addition to full bars both upstairs and downstairs and an exclusive room
                    reserved to hold the largest selection of Cognac in San Francisco.
                    In addition to our all day menu, we offer live jazz music on Saturdays.
                  </Text>
              </View>
          </ScrollView>
      </Screen>
     );
     
     }
}
```

Or if you screen is inside a shoutem extension or you are using `CardStack` from `@shoutem/ui/navigation` in your project you could just remove `ScrollView.DriverProvider` and change the import of `NavigationBar` from `@shoutem/ui` to `@shoutem/ui/navigation`

Comment: it's still not work :( i got error "animate Icon with animation named solidify but you didnt pass driver to Icon". when i dismess that error and try scroll down, i got same result like before i posted above! pls recheck